# Have an issue using L10NManager.setLocale on iPhone

Tags: format, locale, codenameone, currency

I am using L10NManager to format currency and numbers in our App.
e.g. “String formattedString = L10NManager.getInstance().formatCurrency(value);”
This method works fine with device locale-language settings unchanged.

However, I need to set device locale-lang in code: "L10NManager.getInstance().setLocale("gb", "en");"
This method works on Simulator and Android devices, but has no effect on iPhone.

For instance:
Android: £1,000
iPhone: $1,000

Is there some other method I should use to change the locale-lang and format currency on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the set locale API seems to be missing on the iOS port. I've [filed an issue for this](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1679) and set its schedule to the next milestone.